# Raw, very basic bootloader binary in pure Rust?

Tags: assembly, rust, bootloader, boot, low-level

My goal is to do https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/tree/master/01-bootsector-barebones in pure  Rust using `asm`, or rather `global_asm`.

Here's what I tried:

1. Create a new project and create `.cargo/config.toml` with these contents:

   ```
   [build]
   target = "target.json"

   [unstable]
   build-std = ["core", "compiler_builtins"]
   ```
2. Create the `target.json` with these contents:

   ```json
   {
       "llvm-target": "x86_64-unknown-none",
       "data-layout": "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128",
       "arch": "x86_64",
       "target-endian": "little",
       "target-pointer-width": "64",
       "target-c-int-width": "32",
       "os": "none",
       "executables": true,
       "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
       "linker": "rust-lld",
       "panic-strategy": "abort",
       "disable-redzone": true,
       "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
   }
   ```
3. And finally `src/main.rs`:

   ```rs
   #![feature(global_asm)]
   #![no_main]
   #![no_std]

   global_asm!(r#"
   loop:
     jmp loop
   .org 510
   .word 0xaa55
   "# :::: "volatile");

   #[panic_handler]
   fn panic(panic_info: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {
       loop {}
   }
   ```
4. A few setup commands:

   ```
   rustup override set nightly
   cargo install cargo-binutils
   rustup component add llvm-tools-preview
   ```
5. Compile and transform it using `cargo objcopy -- -O binary boot_sect_simple.bin`

This compiles successfully and the next step would be to run the binary in QEMU.
The problem is that this `boot_sect_simple.bin` contains zero bytes.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: This is required reading: https://os.phil-opp.com/minimal-rust-kernel/ See also the [bootloader crate](https://crates.io/crates/bootloader) mentioned in the blog post.

Comment: Using `global_asm` like this is sort of a contradiction of "pure" Rust.  You're really going to be trying to circumvent the behavior of the compiler and linker to get it to build code in a very different way than it would, and I think it's going to be more frustrating than educational.  A boot sector by its nature has to be basically pure assembly, so why not write it like that and cut out the middleman?

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't particularly plan on making it more complex than this loop. I only want to get this simple example to work. This is also about getting to know how `global_asm` works and why it doesn't work here.

Comment: Well, the fundamental problem is that the boot sector runs in 16-bit real mode, for which LLVM support is pretty marginal, see https://github.com/rust-osdev/bootloader/issues/24.